# Acess SharePoint using Microsoft Graph SDK for Java without an access token

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I am trying to connect my Java application to SharePoint. I am able to connect to it via Apache HttpClient using only UserName, Password and Site url without the need to register my app in AAD or any access token.

I am following the connection approach of this answer [Authentication to SharePoint from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609502/8863925)

Now I can connect to SharePoint with only username, password and site url and query lists and so on but the responses need much parsing/handling and I can't full benefit from using the Microsoft Graph SDK.
What I need to do is be able to use the  Microsoft Graph SDK with this kind of authentication (username/password) instead of using an access token / client id ...etc.

Is there a way to handle to solve such a problem? any solution to implement this kind of authentication using Microsoft Graph SDK

Comment: Why do you not want to register your app to AAD?

Comment: @engineerer the use case is for users of my program to be able to use my app to connect to their SharePoint without extra configurations.